# How to send paperclip file compressed to client browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, gzip, content-type

I have an app which allows a user to upload a document and converts it using a paperclip processor.  Unfortunately, the processor converts the file into multiple files (i.e. file, file01, file02).  I then   use gzip to create an archive of the file for paperclip to use (ie. file.gz).

I want to display the gzip file in the show page, I have tried many different ways but cannot get this working. I want to send the gzip file to the client and have the browser deflate it.

`<%= render :file => @asset.document.url(:gzip), :type => "application/x-gzip" %>`

the above produces the standard 'missing template /link/to/file'.

Any suggestions??